# How to use Leak Canary on Android TV

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have an Android TV app which is pre-Lollipop which I need to check for leaks.  I have added Leak Canary to the application and am able to run the app and see the leak canary logo briefly when the application crashes so I know it has been pushed to the device.  On the Leak Canary site I do not see any documentation on how to pull the dump files.  Does anyone know where these files are stored on the device and how I can download and inspect the generated leak detection files?

Answer (score 0):

run this via your adb

```
adb shell am start -n "<Replace com.your.package.name>/leakcanary.internal.activity.LeakLauncherActivity"
```

here's the [ref](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/#android-tv)

---

note:

it has a bug on early version that toast getview() will cause crash.

2.9.1 work fine.